# Cocoa: Application scripts folder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, applescript

Do I have to create the /Users/name/Library/Scripts/Applications/app folder myself? It doesn't seem to be created automatically. Or is there a command to create it?

Comment: Just some info : the script menu has commands to reveal the script folder of the active application. It will create the folder if it not exists. One can activate that menu in Apple-Script Editor's Preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

```
NSError *error;
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[@"~/Library/Scripts/Applications/app" stringByExpandingTildeInPath] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];
```